# How are Bitcoin Signed Messages generated?

Tags: hash, signature, message-signing

Ledger Nano S and other pieces of Bitcoin software and hardware can sign messages using the private key associated with an address.

Doing this, I get the following output:

```
-----BEGIN BITCOIN SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Test
-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----
1BqtNgMrDXnCek3cdDVSer4BK7knNTDTSR
ILoOBJK9kVKsdUOnJPPoDtrDtRSQw2pyMo+2r5bdUlNkSLDZLqMs8h9mfDm/alZo3DK6rKvTO0xRPrl6DPDpEik=
-----END BITCOIN SIGNED MESSAGE-----
```

What exactly is being signed? How is the signature generated? What is the hash preimage that goes into the ECDSA signing algorithm?

Comment: There [docs and sample code](https://github.com/nanotube/supybot-bitcoin-marketmonitor/blob/master/GPG/local/bitcoinsig.py) widely available. Most bitcoin full node implementations also have a `verifymessage` function that you can look at.

Comment: So I need to prepend "\x18Bitcoin Signed Message:\n" + chr( len(message) )  to the message. What encoding is used to transform the string into a byte array, UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message that is signed is prepended with

```
"\x18Bitcoin Signed Message:\n" + compactSizeEncoding( len(message) )
```

\x18 is Python syntax for unicode character `0x18`. This new text string is then converted into a byte array by interpreting the string as UTF8. This will give you the correct hash preimage which is:

```
SHA256(SHA256(utf8.to_bytes("\x18Bitcoin Signed Message:\n" + compactSizeEnc( len(message) + message )) = 
559766ea41f2bc4125e5449200dbf7e902b724b66104820ca5b7fc59f30a19e0
```

You can see a Python code example [here](https://github.com/nanotube/supybot-bitcoin-marketmonitor/blob/master/GPG/local/bitcoinsig.py). The function `msg_magic` generates the hash preimage from the message. This Python code example does not correctly implement compactSizeEnc, however. So it only works with a message length up to 253 bytes.

The correct way of handling compactSizeEncoding is documented [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Variable_length_integer).

Answer (score 1):

The message that was signed is "Test". Will use https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-message-validate command line interface below.

As you can see, I clearly do not have the private keys nor did I have access to the BTC blockchain, but I can validate the message was digitally signed by a person in control of the private key for BTC address 1BqtNgMrDXnCek3cdDVSer4BK7knNTDTSR without the need for possessing the associated BTC public key.

**% echo -n "Test" | bx message-validate 1BqtNgMrDXnCek3cdDVSer4BK7knNTDTSR ILoOBJK9kVKsdUOnJPPoDtrDtRSQw2pyMo+2r5bdUlNkSLDZLqMs8h9mfDm/alZo3DK6rKvTO0xRPrl6DPDpEik=**

`The signature is valid.`

***Result when the message is changed:***

% echo -n **"Tested wrong message"** | bx message-validate 1BqtNgMrDXnCek3cdDVSer4BK7knNTDTSR ILoOBJK9kVKsdUOnJPPoDtrDtRSQw2pyMo+2r5bdUlNkSLDZLqMs8h9mfDm/alZo3DK6rKvTO0xRPrl6DPDpEik=

`The signature is not valid.`

***Result when the wrong public address is applied:***

% echo -n "Test" | bx message-validate **1FZHv7fubXkMcgbDBUeehgPf28cHP86f7V** ILoOBJK9kVKsdUOnJPPoDtrDtRSQw2pyMo+2r5bdUlNkSLDZLqMs8h9mfDm/alZo3DK6rKvTO0xRPrl6DPDpEik=

`The signature is not valid.`

This is the magic of Internet money. The math is documented a bit in the Andreas' [**Mastering Bitcoin Book**](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch06.asciidoc#ecdsa-math). Also see [How is Public Key extracted from (message, digital signature, address)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81232/how-is-public-key-extracted-from-message-digital-signature-address).

Comment: Yeah. It is pretty cool that you can validate a signature with only an address, you don't need the public key.