# Up to 4 Different Points within ECDSA/Public Key Recovery technique

Tags: public-key, ecdsa, message-signing

In the answer to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81232/how-is-public-key-extracted-from-message-digital-signature-address), it is stated that:

> Rearranging this equation you get *rP = sR - mG*, or *P = (s/r)R - (m/r)G*. Thus, it seems we can just compute the public key from the message and the signature. Unfortunately, there can be up to 4 different points *R* for which *R.x mod n = r* (in practice, the number is almost always 2).

How is it possible that there could be up to 4 different points for *R*? And why would it most often be 2 different points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negating an elliptic curve point means negating its Y coordinate (modulo the field size *p*), so *-(x,y) = (x,-y)*. This implies that if you have a point *R* for which *R.x mod n = k* (where *n* is the curve order), then the same will be true for *-R*.

Furthermore, and with negligable probability, it is possible that both *R.x* and *R.x + n* are valid X coordinates (only when *R.x* < p-n). In that case, there are 4 possible points (*(r, y1)*, *(r,-y1)*,*(r+n,y2)*,*(r+n,-y2)*).

Comment: Then, is the reason that _R.x + 2n, R.x + 3n_, etc. are not possible X coordinates because of a size constraint (I'm guessing they would be larger than 256 bits)? Perhaps this is also the reason for why R.x < p-n?

Comment: Yes, p and n are both very close to 2^256, but n is slightly smaller.